# Granting permission to a single document when access is denied to Sharepoint

Tags: excel, access, denied

I'm trying to test limiting access to documents via sharepoint.  I was emailed a link to the an excel document that lives on sharepoint.  I have access denied to sharepoint but access granted to this document.  Does the access denied to all of sharepoint trump the access granted to a single document?

Our administrator, denied the site, but granted access to the document.  However, I have been unable to open it in excel.  I click on it and nothing happens.

Comment: what sharepoint version you are using?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, access to SharePoint will trump access to a document or file that is IN SharePoint. Of course, this is for access to SharePoint at the root level. If you have access to SharePoint but not a specific site, you should still be able to see a document you have permissions for on the site or subsite that you don't have permissions for.

Answer (score 1):

You can have unique permissions down to a document and permissions are additive in sharepoint, ie if a user doesn't have access to your site but has permission on a file then he will be able to see it, or even update it if it is collaborative rigths.

But sharing a document doesn't mean you are giving permission to the file depending on how your site permissions are configured. For example if you share a file using the gui but the "Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders." is disabled, then the "link" to the file will still be sent but no rights will be granted. To be sure the user has proper permissions, select the file --> Shared With --> Advanced and then see the permissions for this particular item.

Hope it helps.